# How to pass reference to this static lifetime struct to each worker stared by the server?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to understand how to accomplish this flow:

- a main function that create a new `Config` struct
- passes it to a function that live until the program is closed (is `'static`)

This is the code and the error I'm getting:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let config = new_config();

    start(config).await.unwrap(); // here the error is: "`config` does not live long enough, borrowed value does not live long enough"
}

pub struct Config {
    pub app_name: String,
    pub host: String,
    pub logging: LoggingConfig,
}

pub struct LoggingConfig {
    pub level: String,
}

fn new_config() -> Config {
    Config {
        app_name: std::env::var("APP_NAME").unwrap(),
        host: std::env::var("HOST").unwrap(),
        logging: LoggingConfig {
            level: std::env::var("LOGGING_LEVEL").unwrap(),
        },
    }
}

pub struct AppState {
    pub config: &'static Config,
}

async fn start(config: &'static Config) -> std::io::Result<()> {
  HttpServer::new(|| {
    App::new()
      .app_data(web::Data::new(AppState {
          config: &config, // this is what I need
      }))
      .route("/", web::get().to(hello))
      .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
      .run()
      .await
}
```

As you can see I want to pass a reference to the `Config` to each server worker without `clone()`.

How to do that?

Comment: The use of `&'static Config` is probably a mistake, I guess you want something like `Arc<Config>`. Then you could use `Arc::new(new_config())` to get it.

Comment: If you *really* need `&'static config`, and are sure there will only ever be one config (or a limited number of them), you could use `Box::leak()` to obtain an `&'static Config`: `let config = Box::leak(Box::new(new_config()))`. But this should only be used if you know what you're doing, not as a substitute for properly using lifetimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`web::Data`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Data.html) is similar to `Arc`; you can clone it, it won't clone the actual data it contains (here `AppState`).

Here is a simple fix of your code.
Once `config` is set up in `main()`, we pass it by **value** (i.e. move) to `start()`.
Then `start()` handles the necessary `web::Data`, cloning...

If the `Config` is not supposed to change, we can keep it as is in `AppState`; only shared references (`&`) will be taken.
In case you need to mutate some part of the `AppState`, I added an example with a `Mutex` protecting a `String`.
Each time the page is loaded, the `String` is extended.

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let config = new_config();
    start(config).await.unwrap(); // pass by value
}

pub struct Config {
    pub app_name: String,
    pub host: String,
    pub logging: LoggingConfig,
}

pub struct LoggingConfig {
    pub level: String,
}

fn new_config() -> Config {
    Config {
        app_name: std::env::var("APP_NAME").unwrap(),
        host: std::env::var("HOST").unwrap(),
        logging: LoggingConfig {
            level: std::env::var("LOGGING_LEVEL").unwrap(),
        },
    }
}

pub struct AppState {
    pub config: Config,
    pub value: Mutex<String>,
}

async fn hello(
    _req: HttpRequest,
    data: web::Data<AppState>,
) -> HttpResponse {
    let config = &data.config;
    let mut value = data.value.lock().unwrap();
    value.push('*');
    let body = format!(
        "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>\
        <p>app_name: {:?}</p>\
        <p>host: {:?}</p>\
        <p>logging level: {:?}</p>\
        <p>value: {:?}</p>\
        </body></html>",
        config.app_name, config.host, config.logging.level, value
    );
    HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("text/html").body(body)
}

async fn start(config: Config) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let app_state = web::Data::new(AppState {
        config,
        value: Mutex::new("".to_owned()),
    });
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(app_state.clone())
            .route("/", web::get().to(hello))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Comment: Wow. I'm studying your answer. Thank you very much. Do we necessarily need `Mutex`?

Comment: @FredHors no it was not for a read-only config. Now the example shows an immutable config and a mutable integer (requiring a `Mutex`).

Comment: There is never a reason to use `Mutex<i32>` in my opinion, use `AtomicI32` instead. (Unless weird embedded special cases). Although I understand that this was probably for demonstration purposes only and your actual data won't be an `i32`.

Comment: @Finomnis yes, and there is no need for a web server in order to increment an integer too... it was an example: how to access a shared resource (of any kind) that we want to mutate. I changed to `String` then.

Comment: @prog-fh thanks for your code. Really, thanks. I'm having an issue tough: I need to use `config` after `let app_state = {}`. With something similar to `println!("{}", config.app_name);` but I'm getting the error: `borrow of moved value: "config" value borrowed here after move rustc E0382`. And it's logical. What do you suggest? Should I clone? I don't want to clone: it's stupid in this case! What's the idiomatic way in this case?

Comment: @FredHors Once the `Config` is moved inside the `AppState` and this `AppState` is hold by a `web::Data` (in order to share it between various requests), the only way to access the `Config` is via the `web::Data`. Probably something like `println!("{}", app_state.config.app_name);` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: You can't.

First, you probably don't want `&'static Config` but rather regular old `&Config`. This would work for normal functions.

When using `async` functions instead, it sadly no longer works, because the compiler cannot guarantee that the async function actually terminates in time and releases the reference. There are multiple reasons for that, but I'm not going to go into detail.

If you really do want to avoid duplicating it, I'd use an `Arc` instead.

Comment: Can you please write an example?

Comment: I could, but I think it would be pointless in this case because @prog-fh's solution is the right way to go.